# WordPress site search causes apache authentication required

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

When using my themes search, or its content tabs, I get prompted for authentication required (not the WordPress login); however, I can manually go to the article without issues, and I can use both the search and content tabs after I entered my credentials. I figured I have something misconfigured somewhere, but I don't know where. I've looked in the .htaccess, the apache .conf for the site, but nothing stood out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check the network-tab for requests to ressources in folders with resctricted access(it may be anything, also images, css & js-files, you should see a 40x-HTTP-status)

Comment: That's weird. It's looks like it's trying to make a call to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. My theme shouldn't be accessing this, correct?

Comment: I just read that /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php actually provides public API's for plugins. I thought it was best practice to lock down /wp-admin/ though?

Comment: admin-ajax.php handles all ajax-requests, not only the ajax-requests for admins(the name of the file may be misleading )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to provide public access to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, which can be done by adding the following to your apache2.conf or .htaccess file.

```
<Files admin-ajax.php>
  Allow from all
  Satisfy any
</Files>
```